# nvarchar max gives 'String or binary data would be truncated'

Tags: java, sql, string, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

I am trying to insert string-values larger than 5500 characters into a MSSQL 2008 database. I get the error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

when I try to insert these values even though the data type of the column is declared nvarchar(max). Is there a cap on the string-size that I can enter? If so, what would be a solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

When i manually enter the data via mgmt studio it works. However, I'm performing the updates via JDBC-driver & prepared statements.

My query is of the form:

```sql
UPDATE table SET columnX = value1 WHERE columnX = value2;
```

- I add this statement to a batch, and once every 1000 statements I execute them.
- value1 in this case contains a large amount of characters.
- columnX is definitely defined as nvarchar(max)

Comment: What does your code and table DDL look like?  Have you tried the absolute simplest test case?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a different column? This error [is infamous](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name) for giving little information.

Comment: Post your query, sample data, and table structures and we can help.  Basically right now you are saying "I can't do this" and we have no information to go on, so the answer to the current question would be "Don't do it that way" which is equally unhelpful.

Comment: Also, which JDBC Driver and JRE are you using? The MS-JDBC implementation has some known and probably some still unknown problems on recent JRE's

Comment: @Durandal I'm using sqljdbc4 with 1.7.0_01 x64 Java

Comment: @JNK added the requested info

Comment: Don't know if it has anything to do with your problem, but that combination is officially not supported by MS. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx

Comment: @Durandal I'm not using any of the methods that the hotfix applies to..

Comment: Have you checked the maximum column width of the jdbc driver you are using?

Comment: @Jeff I can't find documentation on this, but it seems some people have problems with string being truncated in the resultSet when using JDBC. So I guess it has to do with JDBC-limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft encourages us to use the SQLServerPreparedStatement to modify large-value-types like varchar(max).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813.aspx

You could also use a stored procedure to solve the problem, that is what I did, when I had similar problems with JDBC/Pentaho.

You could write a stored procedure on the sql-server that fulfills the task. And just call that stored procedure from your Java-code.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks chris, i'm currently using java's PreparedStatement. How does this differ from the SQLServerPreparedStatement?

Comment: Basically there are different JDBC-Stacks. One is from Microsoft. I really don't know the pros and cons. Maybe this answers your question partly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx